# case giving three results for single switch

Tags: java, switch-statement

So I have this piece of code:

```
void go() {
    String x = "Hi";

    switch (x) {
    case "Hi": 
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

And this returns: Hi

But when I run

```
void go() {
    String x = "Hi";

    switch (x) {
    case "Hi":
        System.out.println("Hi");
    case "Bye":
        System.out.println("Bye");
    }
}
```

It returns:

Hi
Bye

Why is this.Is there something I missed?

Comment: You forgot the `break;`

Comment: you forgot the break; statement after your print, making it follow a waterfall principle

Comment: Except for the last case, you have to add break statements. You can read more here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/switch-statement-in-java/

Answer (score 2):

As already stated before, you have to add `break;` statements for each `case` if you want to stop at that special one. Your code would then look like this:

```
void go() {
    String x = "Hi";

    switch (x) {
    case "Hi":
        System.out.println("Hi");
        break;
    case "Bye":
        System.out.println("Bye");
        break;
    }
}
```

Another thing you really should do is adding a `default` case for any non matching input (imagine someone input `"Hy"` instead of `"Hi"`, there wouldn't be any output for that...):

```
void go() {
    String x = "Hi";

    switch (x) {
    case "Hi":
        System.out.println("Hi");
        break;
    case "Bye":
        System.out.println("Bye");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Your input was \"" + x 
                + "\", please enter either \"Hi\" or \"Bye\" instead!");
    }
}
```

The `default` statement is an option for anything that isn't handled in the `case` statements.

Now back to the `break`s... You can handle different `case`s just the same if you set the breaks only to some of the `case`s:

```
void go() {
    String x = "Hi";

    switch (x) {
    case "Hi":
    case "Hy":
        System.out.println("Hi");
        break;
    case "Bye":
    case "By":
        System.out.println("Bye");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Your input was \"" + x 
                + "\", please enter either \"Hi\", \"Hy\", \"By\" or \"Bye\" instead!");
    }
}
```

Doing like this, you will receive the same output for `"Hi"` and `"Hy"` without duplicating the code that handles both `case`s.

Answer (score 1):

You should put some `break` statements at the end of `case` statements or the execution will propagate to the next `case` statements. Even if it is counter intuitive, it is sometimes useful.

```
switch(int n) {
  case 1: System.out.println("Hello");
  case 2: System.out.println("World");
}
```

Here `switch(1)` will display :

```
Hello
World
```

And `switch(2)` will display :

```
World
```

But with `break` statements :

```
switch(int n) {
  case 1: 
     System.out.println("Hello");
     break;
  case 2: 
     System.out.println("World");
     break;
}
```

Here `switch(1)` will display :

```
Hello
```

And `switch(2)` will display :

```
World
```

Answer (score 0):

In switch statement you have to write break at the end of each case.
If you do not write break then it prints all cases.

```
    switch(value)
    {
       case X:
        //do something
       break;
       case Y:
        //do something
       break;
       default:
       //do something        
      break;
     }
```

Comment: your answer is incomplete and wrong. break; is not mandatory. sometimes (depending on the requirements) it's even wrong to place them.
not placing a break doesn't mean it'll automatically print them all, either, just those until the first break is encountered.